# Iterating over a column and replacing a value with an extracted string [Pandas]

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a dataset, that looks like this:

```
  A   B
1 aa  1234
2 ab  3456
3 bc  [1357, 2468]
4 cc  8901
...
```

I need to iterate over the column B and replace all values in square brackets ([]) with four left digits in those brackets, so the dataset would look like this:

```
  A   B
1 aa  1234
2 ab  3456
3 bc  1357
4 cc  8901
...
```

I have this code:

```
for item in df['B']:
if len(item) > 4:
    item_v = str(item[1:5])
    df['B'][item] = item_v 
    print(df['B'][item])
```

Which prints truncated values, however, if I check the head of the df, it still has the old values:

```
   > df['B'].head()

   >  A   B
    1 aa  1234
    2 ab  3456
    3 bc  [1357, 2468]
    4 cc  8901
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the data in column B actually text?  Or is it a mixture of integers and lists?  If pandas is storing the data as lists, then you will not have a length > 4.  Try running `type(df.loc[3,'B'])` to see what the type is, it may be a list.

Comment: It is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way is to use Pandas [str.get()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html) function and create an other column for the desired results.

**Solution #1**
This first solution works if your values in `B` are integers `[1234,3456,[1357, 2468],8901]`

```
df['C'] = df['B'].str.get(0).astype(float)
df.C.fillna(df['B'], inplace=True)
df['C'] = df.C.astype(int, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
A             B     C
0  aa          1234  1234
1  ab          3456  3456
2  bc  [1357, 2468]  1357
3  cc          8901  8901
```

Then, you can delete column B if you don't need it.

**Solution #2**
This solution works if your values in `B` are strings `['1234','3456',['1357', '2468'],'8901']`

```
import re
df['digits'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+', str(x)))
df['digits'] = df['digits'].str.get(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A             B    digits
0  aa          1234   1234
1  ab          3456   3456
2  bc  [1357, 2468]   1357
3  cc          8901   8901
```

Again, you can delete column B if you don't need it.

Comment: Joe, good approach, but when I ran the code, I got just the first digit of the 4 in column C. For the third line, I got square bracket ([) in column C. Also, I need B/C to be a string.

Comment: @FeyziBagirov So your value probably looks like this `'[1357, 2468]'`. It's not a list of integers, it's a string. You should have explained that.

Comment: @FeyziBagirov Great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are looping over the items in column B of the dataframe, but you don't have a way to index back into your original dataframe. Specifically, the line:

`df['B'][item] = item_v`,

doesn't do what you want. It is placing a new item in column B with an index of `item`. If you try it with a small dataframe, you will probably see some odd values at the end of the frame. When I try this, I get:

```
In[36]: df
Out[36]: 
    A     B
0  aa  1234
1  ab  3456
2  bc  1357
3  cc  8901

In[37]: df['B'][item] = item_v

In[38]: df['B']
Out[38]: 
0       1234
1       3456
2       1357
3       8901
8901    8901 <-- ???
Name: B, dtype: object
```

To make matters worse, this line doesn't insert the value into the dataframe where you would expect. You will only see the new element when you look at `df['B']`. If you look at only `df` you will see the original dataframe without the extra item.

The correct way is to set elements in a dataframe is to use `.loc[]` like:

`df.loc[item,'B'] = item_v`

This still doesn't address the original problem, which is how to get the correct index. One fix for your original code is to accumulate values for each item in column B in a list and then assign it back to column B like this:

```
newB = []
for item in df['B']:
    if len(item) > 4:
        item_v = str(item[1:5])
    else:
        item_v = item
    newB.append(item_v)
print(newB)
df.loc[:, 'B'] = newB
```

However, with `pandas` there are also solutions that don't require directly iterating over the items in column B.

For example, you can use [`.where()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to replace only the strings longer than 4 characters along with the [`.str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) functions to manipulate the text elements. This one liner will do the job:

```
df.loc[:,'B'] = df['B'].where((df['B'].str.len() <= 4), df['B'].str[1:5])
```

This statement creates a Series that contains the item from column B if it is 4 or fewer characters, or the slice [1:5] of the item in column B if it is longer than 4 characters. This series is then assigned to replace column B in `df`.